# How do you connect C# to a remote MySQL Server in Atom?

Tags: c#, mysql, atom-editor

I am using C# 5 on Windows in the Atom IDE with the script package. In order to connect to a PHPMyAdmin MySQL database server, I need the `mysql.data` namespace, but without Visual Studio, I do not know how to include this assembly reference.

```
String server = "localhost";
String database = "connectcsharptomysql";
String uid = "username";
String password = "password";
String connectionString;
connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
   database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
MySqlConnection s = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

I have viewed these posts but they all concern using Visual Studio or a problem with the connection itself.

- [Connecting to MySQL server via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807928/connecting-to-mysql-server-via-c-sharp)
- [How to connect to a MySQL server using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110027/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-server-using-c)

Comment: Do you have csproj file created? Is it .net core project?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya No. I have neither of those because I am not using Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you able to create and run a simple hello world console application using atom?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to do it in Atom because even though I added the assembly I don't know how to reference it within the IDE. I used the command line instead:

1. Download the MySql.Data.dll and put it in the same directory as the c# file
2. Including the `using` directive at the top of the file:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

3. Run in the command line after getting to the directory:

> csc FILENAME.cs /r:MySql.Data.dll

4. Run in the command line

> start FILENAME.exe